# How to send emails if your hosting provider does not allow SMTP relay?

Tags: codeigniter, email, smtp, sendgrid, amazon-ses

I have an application built with CodeIgniter and hosted with a shared hosting provider.

My MX records point to Gmail servers and my app can send emails using Gmail with the standard CodeIgniter e-mail methods.

Now I want to send some transactional mails using SendGrid or Amazon SES. But that does not work and apparently the reason is that my hosting provider does not allow SMTP relaying.

I am thinking of using SendGrid APIs and cURL but I am not sure how well they will work with the CI methods that I am familiar with.

Preferably I would not want to change the MX records that are pointing to Gmail that handles the regular mails for our company.

Given the constraints, is there anything that can be done to send e-mails using SendGrid or Amazon SES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the SendGrid web API to send emails.  If you're ISP is blocking email, then your best bet is to switch to HTTP. It's a pretty simple switch since it takes all the same parameters. Check out the docs for more info:

> http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/web-api/mail/#send

And I doubt it will work with the CI email library, but there's no reason you can't just use the SendGrid library:

> https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

---

Also, this [CodeIgniter library](https://github.com/bold/codeigniter-sendgrid-mail) sends SendGrid email via HTTP.  Might be worth checking out.

Comment: Hi Swift, thanks a lot for the pointers. I will check them out.

Answer (score 4):

You can use alternate ports with SendGrid:

> Many hosting providers and ISPs block port 25 as a default practice. When trying to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net remember that ports 25, 2525, 587, and 465 are all available for use. You can connect via unencrypted or TLS on ports 25, 2525, and 587. You can connect via SSL on port 465.

-- http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/get-started/smtp-ports/

Comment: Hi AKX, thanks for your reply. I have already tried all the ports you mentioned, with unencrypted, SSL and TLS - it did not work either with SendGrid or SES. Both gave the same error.

Comment: That's a crappy service provider then. :( I guess you've talked with their customer service to see if you can change things re SMTP relaying?
Failing that, I guess you'll have to use the HTTP APIs (if they're enough for what you're doing).

Comment: Yes, I have talked to their customer service but nothing came of it. OK I will probably try the APIs then.